# How do i display a count from another table in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I building a blog for school i would like to display the count of comments for each thread made. However I'm a bit lost to how to achieve this goal any help would be great thank you!

i have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_message` (
  `MessageID` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Message` text,
  `AddedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MessageID`)
)


CREATE TABLE `blog_comments` (
  `CommentID` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MessageID` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Author` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CommentMessage` text,
  `AddedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CommentID`),
  KEY `blog_comments_ibfk_1` (`MessageID`),
  CONSTRAINT `blog_comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MessageID`) REFERENCES `blog_message` (`MessageID`)
)
```

my goal is

to display in a gridview

int a table format
Comment count | title | Username | Date of creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is MySQL syntax, not sure what you're using.  But this will return a list MessageIds and the number of comments they have.

```
----------------------------
| MessageId | comment_count|
----------------------------
| 1234      | 34           |
----------------------------

SELECT bm.MessageId, count(bc.CommentId) as comment_count
FROM blog_comments bc, blog_message bm
WHERE bm.MessageId = bc.MessageId
GROUP BY bm.MessageId
```

If you want the Author and AddedDate just add it to the `SELECT` statement (i.e. `SELECT bm.MessageId, count(bc.CommentId) as comment_count, bm.AddedDate, bm.Author`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT 
    bm.MessageID, Count(bc.CommentID) as Cnt, Title, Username, AddedDate
FROM blog_message bm
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_comments bc
     ON bm.MessageID = bc.MessageID
GROUP BY bm.MessageID,Title, Username, AddedDate
```